# How can i write a data frame to a specific partition of a date partitioned BQ table using to_gbq()

Tags: pandas, google-bigquery

I have a dataframe which I want to write to date partitioned BQ table. I am using to_gbq() method to do this. I am able to replace or append the existing table but can't write to a specific partition of the table using to_gbq()

Comment: Please share your code, and exactly the errors you are getting.

Answer (score 3):

Since `to_gbq()` doesn't support it as of yet, I created a code snippet for doing this with BigQuery API client.

Assuming you have an existing [date-partitioned](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#date_timestamp_partitioned_tables) table that was created like this (you don't need to pre-create it, more details later):

```sql
CREATE TABLE
  your_dataset.your_table (transaction_id INT64, transaction_date DATE)
PARTITION BY
  transaction_date
```

and you have a DataFrame like this:

```py
import pandas
import datetime

records = [
    {"transaction_id": 1, "transaction_date": datetime.date(2021, 10, 21)},
    {"transaction_id": 2, "transaction_date": datetime.date(2021, 10, 21)},
    {"transaction_id": 3, "transaction_date": datetime.date(2021, 10, 21)},
]

df = pandas.DataFrame(records)
```

here's how to write to a specific partition:

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client(project='your_project')

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    write_disposition="WRITE_TRUNCATE",
    # This is needed if table doesn't exist, but won't hurt otherwise:
    time_partitioning=bigquery.table.TimePartitioning(type_="DAY")
)

# Include target partition in the table id:
table_id = "your_project.your_dataset.your_table$20211021" 
job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(df, table_id, job_config=job_config) # Make an API request
job.result() # Wait for job to finish
```

The important part is the `$...` part in the table id. It tells the API to only update a specific partition. If your data contains records which belong to a different partition, the operation is going to fail.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that to_gbq() is not supported yet for partitioned tables.
You can check here recent issues https://github.com/pydata/pandas-gbq/issues/43.

I would recommend that using Google BigQuery API client library https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/usage.html

You can upload dataframe to BigQuery table too.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-load-table-dataframe

Comment: I might be wrong, but load_table_from_dataframe is a load which affects your quota, but to_gbq uses streaming API which is not counted against your quota. Might not be a big issue if you don't have to load 1000+ tables per day.d=

Comment: is to_gbq() supporting partitions now ?